# How to hide and unhide textbox in access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How to hide and unhide textbox in access vba, but doesn't change when going to the next record. Please help me

I have tried this code :

```
Private Sub cboserdos_AfterUpdate()
If cboserdos.Value = "Lulus Sertifikasi" Then
            Me.txt1.Visible = False
            Me.lbl1.Visible = False
            Me.txt2.Visible = False
            Me.lbl2.Visible = False
            Me.txt3.Visible = False
            Me.lbl3.Visible = False
            Me.txt4.Visible = False
            Me.lbl4.Visible = False
            Me.Frameserdos.Visible = False
            Me.Label824.Visible = False
 Else
            Me.txt1.Visible = True
            Me.lbl1.Visible = True
            Me.txt2.Visible = True
            Me.lbl2.Visible = True
            Me.txt3.Visible = True
            Me.lbl3.Visible = True
            Me.txt4.Visible = True
            Me.lbl4.Visible = True
            Me.Frameserdos.Visible = True
            Me.Label824.Visible = True

 End If

If cboserdos.Value = "Belum Sertifikasi" Then
             Me.txt1.Visible = False
            Me.lbl1.Visible = False
            Me.txt2.Visible = False
            Me.lbl2.Visible = False
            Me.txt3.Visible = False
            Me.lbl3.Visible = False
            Me.txt4.Visible = False
            Me.lbl4.Visible = False
            Me.Frameserdos.Visible = False
            Me.Label824.Visible = False
 Else
            Me.txt1.Visible = True
            Me.lbl1.Visible = True
            Me.txt2.Visible = True
            Me.lbl2.Visible = True
            Me.txt3.Visible = True
            Me.lbl3.Visible = True
            Me.txt4.Visible = True
            Me.lbl4.Visible = True
            Me.Frameserdos.Visible = True
            Me.Label824.Visible = True
 End If

End Sub
```

Problem is when I click next record there is different data from the textbox change's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *OnCurrent* event - and cut your code for a quarter:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim Visible As Boolean

    Select cboserdos.Value 
        Case "Lulus Sertifikasi", "Belum Sertifikasi"
            Visible = False
        Case Else
            Visible = True
    End Select

    Me.txt1.Visible = Visible 
    Me.lbl1.Visible = Visible 
    Me.txt2.Visible = Visible 
    Me.lbl2.Visible = Visible 
    Me.txt3.Visible = Visible 
    Me.lbl3.Visible = Visible 
    Me.txt4.Visible = Visible 
    Me.lbl4.Visible = Visible 
    Me.Frameserdos.Visible =Visible 
    Me.Label824.Visible = Visible 

End If
```